# How to remove vendor from Customer booking cancelled email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am using WooCommerce Bookings. I've customized the customer-bookings-cancelled template and it works when a customer cancels a booking, but it is sending an email notification to both vendor and customer. I need to remove the vendor from this notification but cannot find any instruction on how to do this. Are there any classes or hooks I can use to strip the vendor from the notification.

```
// Hook into the 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_booking_cancelled' filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_booking_cancelled', 'custom_exclude_vendor_from_customer_email', 10, 2 );

function custom_exclude_vendor_from_customer_email( $recipient, $booking ) {
    // Get the customer email
    $customer_email = $booking->get_customer_email();

    // Get the vendor email(s) - Replace 'vendor' with the appropriate user role for your vendors
    $vendor_emails = array();
    $vendors = get_users( array( 'role' => 'vendor' ) );
    foreach ( $vendors as $vendor ) {
        $vendor_emails[] = $vendor->user_email;
    }

    // Remove vendor emails from the recipient list
    $recipient_emails = array_diff( array( $customer_email ), $vendor_emails );

    // Return the filtered recipient list (customer email only)
    return $recipient_emails;
}
```

Any direction here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand that you're facing an issue, but it would be helpful if you could provide some more information. Could you please share the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our model, we determined that the vendor profile would always be the second recipient and therefore a simple array option worked the best:

```
function remove_vendor_from_cancellation_email( $recipients ) {
    $recipientsArr = explode(',', $recipients);
    $recipient = $recipientsArr[0];
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_booking_cancelled', 'remove_vendor_from_cancellation_email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other method ;

```
/**
 * Remove vendor from cancellation email notification headers.
 */
function remove_vendor_from_cancellation_email_headers( $headers, $booking_id, $booking ) {
    // Remove the vendor email from the "To" headers.
    $to = isset( $headers['To'] ) ? $headers['To'] : '';
    if ( $to ) {
        $to = explode( ',', $to );
        $to = array_diff( $to, array( 'vendor' ) ); // Replace 'vendor' with the actual vendor email
        $headers['To'] = implode( ',', $to );
    }

    // Return the updated headers.
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'remove_vendor_from_cancellation_email_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I only need to remove the vendor from the cancellation email header.